# How to make a screenshot with a C++ application?[•RESOLVED•]

Tags: c++, image, screenshot

I want to make a program that make a screenshot and save it in a bitmap (bmp file).
I Have this code:

```
#include <atlsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <atlimage.h>

using namespace std;


void TakeScreenShot(const std::string& path)
{
    //setting to the screen shot
    keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    //handler of the bitmap that save the screen shot
    HBITMAP hBitmap;

    //I have to give for it time to make it work
    Sleep(100);

    //take the screen shot
    OpenClipboard(NULL);

    //save the screen shot in the bitmap handler 
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);

    //relese the screen shot
    CloseClipboard();

    std::vector<BYTE> buf;
    IStream* stream = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, &stream);
    CImage image;
    ULARGE_INTEGER liSize;

    // screenshot to jpg and save to stream
    image.Attach(hBitmap);
    image.Save(stream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG);
    IStream_Size(stream, &liSize);
    DWORD len = liSize.LowPart;
    IStream_Reset(stream);
    buf.resize(len);
    IStream_Read(stream, &buf[0], len);
    stream->Release();

    // put the imapge in the file
    std::fstream fi;
    fi.open(path, std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::out);
    fi.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buf[0]), buf.size() * sizeof(BYTE));
    fi.close();
}
int main()
{
    string path = "C:\\";

    TakeScreenShot(path);
    return 0;
}
```

First thing I want to say is that i'm approaching windows graphics in C++ for the first time, that's my first program that make screenshots

This program doesn't give me errors but, during the debug, i gives me an error in the `"atlimage.h"` file,

error:

```
>Expression: hBitmap != 0
```

How can I fix that? I think that the real problem is when it has to save the screenshot in the file.
(I think that because while writing this question on stackoverflow I accidentally pressed "Ctrl + V" and stackoverflow detected an image...The program basically do what it has to do but not completely because it doesn't save screenshot on a file, it saves the screenshot in the clipboard :/ )

**EDIT:**
I tried with this other code:

```
#include <atlsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <atlimage.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void TakeScreenShot(const std::string& path, POINT a, POINT b)
{
    //setting to the screen shot
    keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);

    //handler of the bitmap that save the screen shot
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, abs(b.x - a.x), abs(b.y - a.y));;

    //I have to give for it time to make it work
    Sleep(100);

    //take the screen shot
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();

    //save the screen shot in the bitmap handler 
     
    SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
    
    //relese the screen shot
    CloseClipboard();

    std::vector<BYTE> buf;
    IStream* stream = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, &stream);
    CImage image;
    ULARGE_INTEGER liSize;

    // screenshot to jpg and save to stream
    image.Attach(hBitmap);
    image.Save(stream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG);
    IStream_Size(stream, &liSize);
    DWORD len = liSize.LowPart;
    IStream_Reset(stream);
    buf.resize(len);
    IStream_Read(stream, &buf[0], len);
    stream->Release();

    // put the imapge in the file
    std::fstream fi;
    fi.open(path, std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::out);
    fi.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buf[0]), buf.size() * sizeof(BYTE));
    fi.close();
}
int main()
{
    string path = "out.jpg";
    POINT a, b;
    a.x = 0;
    a.y = 0;

    b.x = 800;
    b.y = 800;
    TakeScreenShot(path,a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

And it seems it works, it saves the file and doesn't give any error.
The problem is that the out.jpg file is completely black :/. I think there is an error in the File save instructions. Anyone can help me?

**EDIT 2:**
I have resolved the problem :D
Now I have this code:

```
#include <atlsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <atlimage.h>

using namespace std;


void TakeScreenShot(const std::string& path)
{
    //setting to the screen shot
    keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    //handler of the bitmap that save the screen shot
    HBITMAP hBitmap;

    //I have to give for it time to make it work in pratica guarda
    Sleep(1000); //Modified

    //take the screen shot
    OpenClipboard(NULL);

    //save the screen shot in the bitmap handler
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);

    //relese the screen shot
    CloseClipboard();

    std::vector<BYTE> buf;
    IStream* stream = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, &stream);
    CImage image;
    ULARGE_INTEGER liSize;

    // screenshot to jpg and save to stream
    image.Attach(hBitmap);
    image.Save(stream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG);
    IStream_Size(stream, &liSize);
    DWORD len = liSize.LowPart;
    IStream_Reset(stream);
    buf.resize(len);
    IStream_Read(stream, &buf[0], len);
    stream->Release();

    // put the imapge in the file
    std::fstream fi;
    fi.open(path, std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::out);
    fi.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buf[0]), buf.size() * sizeof(BYTE));
    fi.close();
}
int main()
{
    string path = "sus.jpg";


    TakeScreenShot(path);
    cout << "Calling TakeScreenShot function..." << endl; //added
    Sleep(3000); //added
    return 0;
}
```

I just added the last part with the cout and upped the stop time on line 21 from 100ms to 1000ms.

*Enjoy my experience with this program :)*

Comment: That isn't a valid path to a file.

Comment: I think GetClipboardData returns NULL, therefore hBitmap becomes 0. You need to figure out why. Maybe you are filling the clipboard in the wrong way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata

Comment: @schteppe I think that the clipboard is filled in the correct way because if i press Ctrl+V it paste the screenshot, the problem is on the save in the file part. Can you help me on this piece of code?Now I tried another piece of code, it works and save the file...the only problem is that the file is completely black :/, i will edit the question with the new piece of code